# Explicit intent broadcast receiver - action filter behavior

Tags: android

I am trying to adapt my app to the new Android O approach with regards to intents, particularly broadcast receivers. I had some doubts if I understand properly the new imposed limitations on services/broadcast receivers. I started experimenting a bit. I am targeting API level 27 (min API level 26) and now I am even more confused by the results.

1. create app **com.example.app**
2. declare (AndroidManifest.xml) a broadcast receiver:

```html
<receiver android:name=".BcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.app.WAKE_UP" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

What confused me are the results of **intent invocation** via adb shell:

A) Matching Action

```
am broadcast -n "com.example.app/.BcastReceiver" -a "com.example.app.WAKE_UP"
```

B) Non-matching Action

```
am broadcast -n "com.example.app/.BcastReceiver" -a "nonsense"
```

C) Missing Action

```
am broadcast -n "com.example.app/.BcastReceiver"
```

Any of these A), B) or C) invocations actually cause that application is instantiated, broadcast receiver is called.

It seems that action action intent filter is actually ignored. Therefore I removed the intent filter in AndroidManifest.xml:

```html
<receiver android:name=".BcastReceiver"/>
```

But with that declaration neither A), B) or C) was able to invoke the broadcast receiver. It seems that the intent filter must be present, but it's content is ignored. Any hint why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason today. It is related to `android:exported` flag. As it is stated in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element):

> The default value depends on whether the broadcast receiver contains
>   intent filters. The absence of any filters means that it can be
>   invoked only by Intent objects that specify its exact class name. This
>   implies that the receiver is intended only for application-internal
>   use (since others would not normally know the class name). So in this
>   case, the default value is "false". On the other hand, the presence of
>   at least one filter implies that the broadcast receiver is intended to
>   receive intents broadcast by the system or other applications, so the
>   default value is "true".

If there is missing an intent filter, the broadcast receiver is not exported and thus cannot be invoked from outside of the app. If there is an intent filter, the broadcast receiver is exported by default. **It applies both to services and broadcast receivers - with the [additional limitation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services) that background service of a background app will not be launched.**

There is however still the inconsistency with ignored action, but I personally understand it that if the startservice/broadcast is explicit - naming the target component explicitly/uniquely - there is no reason to consider action intent filter.